# UICollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths weird animation behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I'm using a `UICollectionView` and `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` to achieve maximum efficiency and get the animations for free.

Somehow the animation is triggering only sometimes (maybe cause reuse cells? ) I've created a simple project with one `UIViewController`, a `UICollectionView` and a `UIButton` to help me trigger the animation.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    var cells = [1]
    @IBOutlet weak var sampleCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        reloadVisibleSlides()
    }

    func reloadVisibleSlides() {

        self.sampleCollectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(self.sampleCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems())

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cells.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        var cell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: CGFloat(arc4random() % 256) / 256.0, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
        return cell

    }

}
```

If you compile and run it you will see it only triggers alternatively.

I've also tried surrounding it with `performBatchUpdates`

Is there something I am doing wrong? Is there another way achieve this?

Comment: try wrapping it into a collectionView.performBatchUpdates: block

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Already tried that, you can see it at the end of my question.

Comment: Try a better random color generator perhaps and generate and RGB value?

Comment: The color generator is just to show the example, it happens with any kind of change on the cell, thanks for the suggestion anyway :)